# Trying to integrate oidc-react with Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement my own custom sign up/log in pages without the hosted UI. This is my config:

```
const config = {
    authority: '<COGNITO_DOMAIN>',
    clientId: '<CLIENT_ID>',
    redirectUri: 'localhost:3000/',
    responseType: 'code',
    scope: 'openid email profile',
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <AuthProvider {...config}>
            <App />
        </AuthProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

After my app boots up, I instantly get a CORS error like the following:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://<CUSTOM_DOMAIN_NAME>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if I need to somehow enable CORS on the AWS Cognito side (can't find the option)